# if statements not working in Lua

Tags: lua

Here is my code. I am playing tekkit and want to control the water flow.  There is redstone power on the brown wire but not the black, but it still goes to `ERROR!` Anyone know what is my problem?

in Lua code:

```
shell.run("clear")
brown = rs.testBundledInput("back", colors.brown)
black = rs.testBundledInput("back", colors.black)
t = true
f = nil

if brown == t and black == f then
  redstone.setBundledOutput("back", restone.getBundledOutput("back") -colors.brown)
  print("All water is flowing.")
  sleep(3)
  shell.run("2")
elseif brown == f and black == t then
  redstone.setBundledOutput("back", restone.getBundledOutput("back") -colors.black)
  print("All water is flowing.")
  sleep(3)
  shell.run("2")
elseif brown == t and black == t then
  redstone.setBundledOutput("back", restone.getBundledOutput("back") -colors.brown)
  redstone.setBundledOutput("back", restone.getBundledOutput("back") -colors.black)
  print("All water is flowing.")
  sleep(3)
  shell.run("2")
elseif brown == f and black == f then
  print("All water is flowing.")
  sleep(3)
  shell.run("2")
else
  print("ERROR!")
end
```

Comment: Proper indentation would make your code *much* easier to read.

Comment: sorry to be that guy.. but t = true, f = nil? why? seriously why?

Comment: Same goes for global `brown` and `black`. They should probably be `local`. See [_Programming in Lua_](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html).

Answer (score 7):

From the code, I'm guessing `brown` and `black` are boolean types, which are either `true` or `false`. But you are comparing them with:

```
t = true
f = nil
```

which is incorrect, because though both `false` and `nil` are false values, they are not the same, i.e, `false` is not equal to `nil`. So change it to `f = false`.

However, that's a little redundant, you don't need `t` and `f` in the if-statements. When you use:

```
if brown == t and black == f then
```

You can test them with this instead:

```
if brown and not black then
```

Comment: For a few minutes, I kept looking at `"back"` in the question and wondered why'd you use *brown* and *black* in your answer. :-/

Comment: Good friendly answer. Thank you for that! But for me this question just creates a new one: Why would anybody ever do this? It's not easier, makes less sense.. there must be a reason? Or at least a story?

Comment: @starmole I'm not following your question ,what did you mean "this" in "Why would anybody ever do this", did you mean statement like `if brown and not black then`?

Comment: Yes. Why? t = true and f = nil. I could see a novice do t = true; f = false. But why f = nil? f even starts with f for false. So there was some thought. Your answer was perfectly right, helpful, and polite btw! I just think there is something to learn in why the question was asked like this.

Comment: @starmole That bothers me as well, especially with the name of the variables `t` and `f` like you said. Maybe the OP is confused about the usage of `nil`, as `nil` can be used as a false value, which mistakenly lead him to think `nil` and `false` are the same.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I feel stupid now. and the reason i am doing this is when i am done i can control my set of nuclearclear reactor from one computer with a few clicks of a button.